# return to Activity's onActivityResult from fragment's child

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

ActivityCat starts DialogFragmentLoves with `show()`. Then DialogFramentLoves starts ActivityDog with `startActivityForResult`. When ActivityDog returns, naturally it calls the `onActivityResult` method that is inside the Fragment. But I want the data to go to ActivityCat. But doing as follows inside DialogFragmentLoves does not work:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    getActivity().onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    dismiss();
}
```

What's the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the documentation of startActivityForResult in Fragment says

> Call startActivityForResult(Intent, int) from the fragment's containing Activity.

So actually it should work as it is now. Maybe it's enough to not override onActivityResult in your fragment? Or maybe you're not calling super.onActivityResult()? Another option might be to call getActivity().startActivityForResult instead...although this should be exactly what the fragment's method seems to do...